# Plivo PHP API 4.0, can't get callstatus or duration (action URL does not execute?)

Tags: php, status, phone-call, duration, plivo

I hope you can help me with an issue with phone call dialings using Plivo PHP (new SDK 4.0). First I will indicate what I want to achieve:
- A client on my website wants to talk with an agent of main, so he introduces his telephone number in a form, choose an agent, and finally when submit, the website connect both of them dialing (this works). But then, (here begin my problems), I can't retrieve the call details (status, duration, initial and end dates of the call, etc...) for invoicing the client according to some of these details.

Edited 2018/02/23:

Ramya, the 600 error has dissapeared and everything seems to be ok as I see in the Plivo debug log. Below are **my new codes** (I think better done thanks to your instructions), and **then, I show you the Plivo debud log** (perhaps it's better you can see it inside my account, call made Feb 23, 2018 18:33:15), and finally I see **my server debug error log is empty!.**

The main problem is that dialstatus.php file, although seems to receive the parameters, I don't know how to access them because dialstatus.php does not execute showing the data in my monitor (in my code for example, this line never shows in the monitor screen:)

```
echo "Status = $estado, Aleg UUID = $aleg, Bleg UUID = $bleg";
```

So even though it receives the parameters, I can not access them to manipulate them, print them on the screen, do ifs with them, etc. May it be perhaps a permission problem with the files? (These php files have 6,4,4 permissions on my server, the same as the others).

Thank you!

**Code 1: makecall.php**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Plivo\RestClient;

$client = new RestClient("**********", "**************************");

$telefono_cliente = "34*******";
$telefono_experto = "34*********";
$duracion = 50;

try {
$response = $client->calls->create(
    "3491111111",
    [$telefono_experto],
    "https://www.ejemplo.com/llamar/response.php?telf=$telefono_cliente",
    'POST',

    [
        'time_limit' => $duracion,
    ]
);

$id = $response->requestUuid;
echo "<br>Este es el requestUuid: " . $id . "<br><br>";

}
catch (PlivoRestException $ex) {
print_r($ex);
}

?>
```

**Code 2: response.php**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Plivo\XML\Response;

$resp = new Response();

    $params = array(
        'callerId' => '3491111111',
        'action' => "https://www.ejemplo.com/llamar/dialstatus.php",
        'method' => "POST",
        'redirect' => "false"
    );

    $body3 = 'Desde ejemplo un cliente desea hablar con usted.';
    $params3 = array(
        'language' => "es-ES", # Language used to read out the text.
        'voice' => "WOMAN" # The tone to be used for reading out the text.
    );
    $resp->addSpeak($body3,$params3);    

    $dial = $resp->addDial($params);
    //$number = "34**********";
    $number = $_GET['telf'];
    $dial->addNumber($number);

    Header('Content-type: text/xml');
    echo($resp->toXML());

/*
Output:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Speak language="es-ES" voice="WOMAN">Desde ejemplo un cliente desea hablar con usted.</Speak>
    <Dial redirect="false" method="POST" action="http://www.ejemplo.com/llamar/dialstatus.php" callerId="3491111111">
        <Number>34********</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
*/
?>
```

**Code 3: dialstatus.php**

```
// Print the Dial Details
$estado = $_REQUEST['DialStatus'];
$aleg = $_REQUEST['DialALegUUID'];
$bleg = $_REQUEST['DialBLegUUID'];

echo "Status = $estado, Aleg UUID = $aleg, Bleg UUID = $bleg";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

1. Redirect = true is used only when you want to continue the call by returning another XML in your action URL. For you use case, you don't have to use this parameter. Even if the Redirect is set to false, Plivo will make a request to the action URL with a list of parameters. I looked into your account ([here](https://manage.plivo.com/logs/debug/call/333e0b82-c462-47d9-876a-b97bb2121292/)) and I can see this request getting sent with DialStatus, ALegUUID, BLegUUID along with other parameters.
2. Dial Action URL is the best place to know the DialStatus and DialHangupCause.

You can find the call duration and billing amount in [Hangup URL request](https://api-reference.plivo.com/latest/net/plivo-xml/request) as well. This Hangup URL can be configured in your first API call (to the expert). By default, hangup URL is set to Answer URL.

Please raise a [support ticket](https://support.plivo.com/) with us for further assistance.

Comment: Thanks Ramya! But what I can't understand (for sure is easy) is why the "dial_status.php" file for printing in screen the results, is not running (perhaps it receives the parameters correctly, but not executes for showing them in screen or handle them with variables). In other words: my question is whether I should run the file "dial_status.php (code 3)" by my own means, or it should run automatically? (In my tests it doesn't run atomatically) so if you could explain how it works and give me an example, it would be great. (I opened a ticket, but the answer was one line without any clearance!).

Comment: dial_satus.php should get executed automatically and need not be run manually. Do you see this request coming in to your server? Can you set redirect=false? You could use Requestb.in (https://requestb.in/) HTTP monitoring tool to check if the requests are hitting the action URL. Just replace the action URL with a requestb.in url and run a test.

Comment: Thanks Ramya! At least I know it should run automatically but there's no lucky yet. I have edited the post with the results of: 1) setting redirect=false (with this, the call debug from Plivo gets an error 600). 2) testing requestb.in. Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: From your requestb.in output, it is clear that Plivo is making a request to your action url. In the server where dial_status.php is hosted, do you see any logs for incoming requests? Plivo will notify this url when the Dial ends. i'm checking why there was a 600 status, but I can see logs for requests sent to dial_status.php. Can you please check your server logs and add some debug lines?

Comment: Hi Ramya and thank you! I edited with the last changes according to your instructions. The errors has dissapeared (there's no 600 error) but dialstatus.php doesn't executes and show in monitor screen although received the parameters.

Comment: It will not open up dial_status.php on your browser. Instead, you could add print/debug lines and check the output in your server terminal.